# Python BeautifulSoup print koi8-r encoded text as Cyrillic

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

Here is my program

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import sys

print (sys.stdout.encoding)
url = "http://autochel.ru/car/motors/foreign/ford/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser", from_encoding = "koi8r")
rows=soup.find_all('tr', {"id" : re.compile("^row")})
print(len(rows))
for row in rows:
    print  (row.text)
```

It returns strings like this

> \xd0\xa7\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd0\xba

which is

> Челябинск

in KOI8-R encoding as i checked, and i need this value being printed to console.

I'm totally newbie in python, so i tried anything i could find: I tried to set default encoding with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: koi8-r -*-
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

i tried `row.text.encode()`  to utf-8, to koi8-r

And i'm a bit tired and dissapointed so, i'm asking community to help me. I'll be really happy, if you help me.

Comment: do you get error message ? always add full error in question. Problem can be `console` which can use different encoding so you have to use the same.

Comment: no, console prints text as "xd0\xa7\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb" and i want it to be printed as normal Cyrillic text

Comment: what shows `sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: cp437 as i see. Even if i use # -*- coding: koi8-r -*- it stays cp437

Comment: so your console can display only encoded to `cp437` (Code Page 437). you can try `row.text.encode('cp437')`. But this code page may not have Cyryllic chars.

Comment: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 8-14: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: see in wikipedia [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) - this code page can't display Cyrillic. You have to use different codepage in system or in console.

Comment: if you use Windows see [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8). (I use Linux and I don't know if this works in Windows)